# Incorrect message for php upload error

Tags: javascript, php

I have these 2 files consisting of the upload.php for uploading files with their respective errors maintained in the session variable and the second file that checks against the session variable error to display the alert messages for the appropriate error. But I am getting the same error that is "Filetype not supported" even if it is supported instead of getting, "Upload size should be less than 10MB" or so.

upload.php=>

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
$sessionid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

  $file= $_FILES['file'];
  $fileName= $file['name'];
  $fileTmpName= $file['tmp_name'];
  $fileSize= $file['size'];
  $fileError= $file['error'];
  $fileType= $file['type'];
  $fileExt = explode('.',$fileName);
  $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

  $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf','tiff','bmp');

  if(in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed)){
    if($fileError=== 0){
      if($fileSize<15728640){
        $fileDestination = '../files/'.$sessionid.'/'.$fileName;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination);
        header("Location: ../index.php?upload=success");
      } else {
        $_SESSION['errors']['size'] = 1;
        session_write_close();
        header("Location: ../index.php?upload=size_exceeded_10MB");
      }
    } else {
      $_SESSION['errors']['upload'] = 1;
      session_write_close();
      header("Location: ../index.php?upload=error");
    }
  } else{
    $_SESSION['errors']['type'] = 1;
    session_write_close();
    header("Location: ../index.php?upload=typeerror");
  }
```

error.php=>

```
<?php
          if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['size']) && $_SESSION['errors']['size'] == 1){ ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('File should be less than 3MB!');
              </script>
          <?php }
          else if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['upload']) && $_SESSION['errors']['upload'] == 1){ ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('Error uploading the file!');
              </script>
          <?php }
          else if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['type']) && $_SESSION['errors']['type'] == 1){ ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('Filetype not supported!');
              </script>
<?php } ?>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])){
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);
} ?>
```

Comment: Try this `if (in_array($fileType, $allowed)){`

Comment: The problem isn't with upload.php. Its there in error.php. And "if(in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed))" is already being used.

Comment: Make sure `session_start();` is called in error.php

Comment: It is being called in it as I'm not submitting it but including the php code itself to my main index.php which does have a session_start otherwise it would have showed the error of $_SESSION.

Comment: That's right, but you can use `die()` to debug your code, for example put `die('allowed ext')` after checking the file extension to see if the problem come from `session` or `in_array` function:   `if (in_array ( $fileActualExt, $allowed ) ) { die('allowed ext'); ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

For "Filetype not supported" error, try to use this code in `$allowed`

```
$allowed = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png','image/pdf','image/tiff','image/bmp');
```

For  "Upload size should be less than 10MB"  error, check your php.ini in your php file

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 21M
```

Comment: The upload.php works fine and I have configured the file size as well in php.ini. When the error does occur, after the redirection using header, the url shows the appropriate error but the error.php doesn't (it shows "filetype not supported" alert for every error.

Comment: Sorry dude, doesn't mean to said your code are wrong, but can you try to change the `$allowed` first even that code is run ?

Comment: I did change it and it still shows the same alert error "Filetype not supported" for supported files exceeding size 10MB.